# jQuery DataTables not re-drawing the table after first load

Tags: jquery, datatables

using vanila dataTables for basic stuff
using server side processing 
i have the following JS code:
[image]

upon first load of the page, everything is fine 
this is the json i received from the server

[image]

everything is working fine so far..

but then, when i press "next" 
all i get is this:
[image]

and nothing... the table doesn't reload the new rows..

in the debugger i can see that the browser (dataTables) did make another request, and that my php is sending the right data
[image]

...so it seems dataTables isn't refreshing the table view. do i have to call some function to make it refresh? i just followed the most basic example online and it didn't say anything about callbacks to make this work.

Comment: It would help if you linked to the "basic code example" you followed along with supplying some actual code and/or error from the console. The jQuery datable website shows it to be pretty simple. Could it be your server is returning data out of order confusing datable. If you are hitting next, why is the ID value going down and not up (is it sorted descending)?

Comment: @steveB -screenshot of the script already pasted,there's nothing more to that. the rest is just the HTML TABLE and the PHP script outputting the dataset .. ID goes down on NEXT coz yes, its' ordered by dec 
i also pasted output from the debugger and it's the same script that outputted the initial data which worked fine (datatable rendered).. its' only when i hit NEXT or change the length or even clicking column to sort.. 
it seems datatable isn't re-rendering upon new data.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.. seems the draw var needs to be incremented, or changed at least. if server sends back the same draw number (=1) then the table wont reload or something..
grrr... this wasn't very clear in the documents.. anyway..